# Recording audio in the background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am creating an application for sound recording. Everything works, but only when the app is active, and when I minimize the recording immediately stops on the iPhone. I use Audio Expo. If someone needs to do something so that the recording does not stop, I will be very grateful

```
app.json
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "audio"
        ]
      }
    },
```

```
app.js

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const [recording, setRecording] = React.useState();
  const [recordings, setRecordings] = React.useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");

  const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = 'background-location-task';
  
  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      console.log('Requesting permissions..');
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });

      console.log('Starting recording..');
      const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync( Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
      );
      setRecording(recording);
      console.log('Recording started');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    setRecording(undefined);
    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();

    let updatedRecordings = [...recordings];
    const { sound, status } = await recording.createNewLoadedSoundAsync();
    updatedRecordings.push({
      sound: sound,
      duration: getDurationFormatted(status.durationMillis),
      file: recording.getURI()
    });

    setRecordings(updatedRecordings);
  }

  function getDurationFormatted(millis) {
    const minutes = millis / 1000 / 60;
    const minutesDisplay = Math.floor(minutes);
    const seconds = Math.round((minutes - minutesDisplay) * 60);
    const secondsDisplay = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
    return `${minutesDisplay}:${secondsDisplay}`;
  }

  function getRecordingLines() {
    return recordings.map((recordingLine, index) => {
      return (
        <View key={index} style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.fill}>Recording {index + 1} - {recordingLine.duration}</Text>
          <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => recordingLine.sound.replayAsync()} title="Play"></Button>
        </View>
      );
    });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{message}</Text>
      <Button
        title={recording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
        onPress={recording ? stopRecording : startRecording} />
      {getRecordingLines()}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  fill: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 16
  },
  button: {
    margin: 16
  }
});
```

I read the documentation, tried to use the Task Manager from Expo

Answer (score 2):

Hey try adding `staysActiveInBackground:true` in your `setAudioModeAsync` like so:

```
  await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
    allowsRecordingIOS: true,
    playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
    staysActiveInBackground:true
  });
```

However, this is not available in Expo Go for iOS, it will only work in standalone apps. (It does seem to work in iOS simulator)

Answer (score 1):

Try following, it will work

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { init, AudioRecorderPlayer, AudioEncoderAndroidType, AudioSourceAndroidType } from 'react-native-audio-recorder-player';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    init({
      audioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
      AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
    });
  }, []);

  const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await AudioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await AudioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Audio Recorder Player Example</Text>
      <Button title="Start Recording" onPress={startRecording} />
      <Button title="Stop Recording" onPress={stopRecording} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```