# How do you start an audio recording when a react native app is in background state on IOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, background-process, expo-av

I have been trying to create a 10-second recording that is started using the function StartRecording which is called inside a useEffect function, I am using expo audio by the way. The function works fine when the dev build is in the foreground but when it goes into the background the StartRecording function does not run it only runs after I bring the app back into the foreground. can anyone help me with this, please?

i have tried bundling it together with background location from expo but it didn't work i only got the location data and the recording still didn't start.

Comment: Apps can't start recording when they are in the background. It would be a privacy issue

Answer (score 0):

```js
await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
  allowsRecordingIOS: true,
  playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
  staysActiveInBackground:true // you need this line
});
```

I was struggling with this for weeks, until I stumbled upon this
Stack Overflow post: [Recording audio in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75558505/recording-audio-in-the-background)

Comment: Refer following link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77626291/15716725